# Set custom application for file comparison in caja

Tags: settings, file-comparison, caja

How can I set custom application which is being invoked when I press "Differences" button in "File Conflict" dialog?

[image: File Conflict Dialog]

I did not find corresponding option in "File Management Preferences".
I did not find it using "dconf Editor" in `org.mate.caja.*`.
I did not find it in files located at `/usr/share/caja` and `~/.config/caja`.
Where is this option being stored at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `meld` installed? If so, the "Differences..." button is provided as part of `meld`'s integration. To change the application invoked would apparently require uninstallation of meld (in which case the "Differences..." button will no longer be present) and installation of a custom application designed to similarly integrate with `caja`.

Bit of background...
The "Differences..." button wasn't present in my `caja` install. I ran across a comment at https://superuser.com/questions/1436673/vimdiff-show-differences-with-only-parent-rows#comment2168027_1436673 indicating that `meld` integrates with `caja`. On installing `meld` and restarting `caja`, the "Differences..." button was there and invoked `meld`.